# UIButton is not being recognized when I touch it due to the UILongPress

Tags: ios, uibutton, sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game that recognizes when a person is holding down his/her finger and moves a player when it is held down. On top of this, I am trying to create a back button in order to go back to the home screen.
This is my code for these two things:

```
- (void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
holdingFinger = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
holdingFinger.minimumPressDuration = 0;
holdingFinger.numberOfTapsRequired = 0;
holdingFinger.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
holdingFinger.allowableMovement = 100;
[view addGestureRecognizer:holdingFinger];

changeScene = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[changeScene addTarget:self action:@selector(changeScene) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[changeScene setTitle:@"Home" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
changeScene.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
changeScene.frame = CGRectMake(410, 0, 70, 30);
[self.view addSubview:changeScene];}

- (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    //NSLog(@"isHoldingDown = YES");
    isHoldingDown = YES;
} else if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    //NSLog(@"isHoldingDown = NO");
    isHoldingDown = NO;
}}

- (void) changeScene {
[changeScene removeFromSuperview];
SKScene* nextScene = [[ATOpenScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition* transition = [SKTransition doorsOpenVerticalWithDuration:0.5];
[self.view presentScene:nextScene transition:transition];
```

}

Both of these things work as I want them to on their own, however, when I put them both in, I am unable to press the button. Is there a simple fix / a careless mistake that I am making here? And if so what would it be? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your holdingFinger.minimumPressDuration = 0; should be greater than 0 to work with the tapgesture

Comment: That works! But is there any other way to do it so that I don't lose some of the aspects of the game? In the game, the player is supposed to be controlling a space ship and the thrust is to be applied immediately when the player touches the screen so a delay in this would kind of take away from the game experience.

Comment: you could add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIButton and have it simultaneously work with the UILongPressGestureRecognizer. Use this method:
(BOOL) gestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer*)                                              gestureRecognizer

shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer: (UIGestureRecognizer*) otherGestureRecognizer